# Проблема отправки письма через Thunderbird

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email

Появилась такая проблема. После обновления Ububntu с 14.10 на 15.04 почтовый клиент Thunderbird 38.2.0 перестал отправлять письма с вложениями. Пробывал, сносить. Не помогло. Есть соседний комп с Ubuntu 14 и там на той же учетке и с той же версией всё работает. Письма с текстом уходят нормально, а вот с вложениями зависает на 97%. Подскажите куда копать. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте поменьше размер вложения.

Comment: 1КБ это много? Пробывал так же разные типы файлов. До обновления всё было нормально.

Comment: Не, 1 килобайт не должен быть проблемой. Может, сбились настройки сервера? Попробуйте с другим SMTP-провайдером.

Comment: Не могу мне нужен именно этот провайдер. Так же отмечу что через веб маорду вложения отправляются.

Comment: А вы всё же попробуйте. Иначе как локализовать ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Включите логи SMTP. Для этого в переменных окружения нужно задать

```
export NSPR_LOG_MODULES=SMTP:4
export NSPR_LOG_FILE=/var/log/thunderbird.log
# start thunderbird
```

После посмотрите на какой операции спотыкается.

См. также: [Logging](https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Logging) (по-английски)

Comment: спасибо за ответ. подскажите в каком файле добавить это?

Comment: Нужно создать текстовый файлик, назвать, например, `tb-debug.sh` написать туда указанные строки (третьей строкой вызывать сам TB, я не знаю где он у вас в файловой системе лежит). Потом вызвать этот скрипт `sh tb-debug.sh`

Comment: Кстати я вот так лихо предложил вариант с логами. Там будет довольно большой лог. Если не знаете как выглядит протокол SMTP, дополните вопрос последним десятком строк перед зависанием, посмотрим.